# Read HttpContent in WebApi controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpcontent

How can I read the contents on the PUT request in MVC webApi controller action.

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int accountId, Contact contact)
{
    var httpContent = Request.Content;
    var asyncContent = httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
...
```

I get empty string here :(

What I need to do is: figure out "what properties" were modified/sent in the initial request (meaning that if the `Contact` object has 10 properties, and I want to update only 2 of them, I send and object with only two properties, something like this:

```
{

    "FirstName": null,
    "LastName": null,
    "id": 21
}
```

The expected end result is

```
List<string> modified_properties = {"FirstName", "LastName"}
```

Answer (score 165, accepted):

By design the body content in ASP.NET Web API is treated as forward-only stream that can be read only once.

The first read in your case is being done when Web API is binding your model, after that the `Request.Content` will not return anything.

You can remove the `contact` from your action parameters, get the content and deserialize it manually into object (for example with Json.NET):

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int accountId)
{
    HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
    string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    CONTACT contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CONTACT>(jsonContent);
    ...
}
```

That should do the trick (assuming that `accountId` is URL parameter so it will not be treated as content read).

Comment: Thanx. And yes, account id is a url param.

Comment: I wonder if you could create a MessageHandler that called LoadIntoBuffer() on the request content before the Model binder kicked in.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I'm not sure if ASP.NET Web API would still bind the model - needs to be tested.

Comment: Will this cause Deadlocking?

Comment: @Airn5475 As it is, it may. You should switch action signature to async and use await.

Comment: @tpeczek why can it only be read once? Just wondering if there was any reason for this when they designed it.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave It's a network stream. So unless you buffer it, it's a read once, forward only stream due to actual source of data.

Comment: I'm using .NET 5.0 and in my method, my Request object (MicrosoftAspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest) I have a ContentLength and ContentType  (both with correct values)  but I don't see a Content property?  Am I missing something? I'm trying to figure out how to read the file I'm posting to the API.  It's of type application/x-msdownload.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter This answer is specific to ASP.NET Web API (old good .NET Framework one). A lot has changed in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 22):

You can keep your CONTACT parameter with the following approach:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var context = (HttpContextBase)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
    context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
    string requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Returned for me the json representation of my parameter object, so I could use it for exception handling and logging.

Found as accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901906/how-to-get-hold-of-content-that-is-already-read)

Answer (score 5):

Even though this solution might seem obvious, I just wanted to post it here so the next guy will google it faster.

If you still want to have the model as a parameter in the method, you can create a `DelegatingHandler` to buffer the content.

```
internal sealed class BufferizingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And add it to the global message handlers:

```
configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new BufferizingHandler());
```

This solution is based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901906/how-to-get-hold-of-content-that-is-already-read) by [Darrel Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819/darrel-miller).

This way all the requests will be buffered.

Comment: I think that might tank my server perf... but it could come in handy.