# Web Api Request Throws "Error while copying content to a stream."

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement this [code example](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api), but get a `HttpRequestException` - "*Error while copying content to a stream*." when the `ReadAsStringAsync()` method is called.  The inner exception is "*Cannot access a disposed object*."  I'm using Fiddler to make the request.  I don't understand. Can someone explain why I'm getting this exception and offer a solution?

Web Api Method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    try
    {
        var jsonString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        throw;
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Fiddler (POST):

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:23567
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Body{"Test":1}
```

Edit:

I have a clue, but need verification.  On the Web Api controller, I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` and in its `OnActionExecuting` override, there's this line:

```
public override async void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // omitted code
    actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

Could it be that because the Content is read here, it's not available again?  If so, how can I make it available in the method?  Is the Content here the same as the HttpRequestMessage?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021089/why-is-the-body-of-a-web-api-request-read-once) may contain an answer.

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov...I'm using Fiddler

Comment: Is this method a Web API action?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov...Yes, it's a method on a Web Api controller

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov...Please see my edit, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the controller's `ActionFilterAttribute's` `OnActionExecuting` method is calling `ReadAsStreamAsync`, the Content can't be read again.  I  changed `ReadAsStreamAsync` to `ReadAsStringAsync` and the request's Content is available in the controller.  Apparantly, ReadAsStringAsync buffers the Content so it's still available.  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021089/why-is-the-body-of-a-web-api-request-read-once) provided the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Just a guess, should post as comment but I want include a code snippet:

Maybe you call `Post` function inside a `using` block, but don't use `await`.

```
using (HttpRequestMessage request = ...)
{
    // Maybe you use this:
    Post(request);

    // Instead of this
    var response = await Post(request);
}
```

Or you don't dispose old connects properly.

Also, try add `HttpVersion.Version10` to your request, which change header request from `Connection: keep-alive` to `Connection: close`, which can cause exception in some case you reuse a host (Search for more info)

```
request.Version = HttpVersion.Version10;
var jsonString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, no luck with these

Answer (score 3):

I resolved with this, my problem was that the response was in gzip:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
        {
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                             DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }
        client = new HttpClient(handler);

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(valoresPost);
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        
                var contenidoPdf = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this (late) post will help someone someday...

In short: the accepted answer suggests to read the entire file as string (and not as stream) in order to bypass a read problem

BUT... reading a file as a string is not such a great idea

I figured out that replacing **MultipartFormDataStreamProvider** with **MultipartMemoryStreamProvider** works great - and let you read your uploaded file as desired

My code (at least the relevant parts of it)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload/file")] // you may replace this route to suit your api service
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            return BadRequest("Unsupported media type");
        }

        try
        {
            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            if (provider.Contents.Count == 0) return InternalServerError(new Exception("Upload failed"));

            var file = provider.Contents[0]; // if you handle more then 1 file you can loop provider.Contents

            var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            // .. do whatever needed here

            return Ok();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding to the conversation, as I encountered this error in a different context. For me I had an existing call from my web app to a separate API. It was previously working and then stopped and I was getting this error and couldn't track down the reason why. What it turned out to be was a circular reference in my entity framework, essentially navigation property between two objects that shouldn't have been there. It wasn't breaking the API as I assume EF has a default configuration for the depth that navigation properties will be populating to prevent a stack overflow, but it must have been overwhelming the stream on the receiving end and causing the connection to time out.

Comment: That was an issue that I ran into.  Thanks for the info.