# HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-7.1

Getting error while attempting to serialize Room model that contains IFormFile and List. Tried many solutions and seen many videos on youtube but this is my first time using mvc web because the client needs an admin dashboard.
I have erased and edited the code but all results to error. looking for someone to help me with a working solution.

The Rooms Model

```
 public class Room
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string? RoomNumber { get; set; }
     public decimal PricePerNight { get; set; }
     public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }
     public ICollection<RoomType> RoomType { get; set; }
     public int BookingStatusId { get; set; }
     public ICollection<BookingStatus> BookingStatus { get; set; }
     public string? Description { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Reservation>? Reservations { get; set; }
     public IFormFile CoverPhoto { get; set; }
     public string? CoverPhotoURL { get; set; }
     public List<IFormFile> GalleryFiles { get; set; }
     public List<RoomImage> Roomimages { get; set; }
 }
```

The Api Controller

```
[HttpPost("AddNewBook")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewBook([FromBody] Room model)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         var file = $"{guid}.jpg";
         if (model.CoverPhoto != null)
         { 
             string folderONE = "wwwroot/img/cover/";
             using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
             {
                 model.CoverPhoto.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                 byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                 var response = FilesHelper.UploadImage(memoryStream, folderONE, file);
             }
             model.CoverPhotoURL = file;
            
         }

         if (model.GalleryFiles != null)
         {
             model.Roomimages = new List<RoomImage>();
             foreach (var filexx in model.GalleryFiles)
             {
                var guidTWO = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                 var fileTWO = $"{guidTWO}.jpg";
                 string foldertwo = "wwwroot/img/rooms/";
                 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                     filexx.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                     byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                     var response = FilesHelper.UploadImage(memoryStream, foldertwo, file);
                 }
                 var gallery = new RoomImage()
                 {
                     Imageurl = fileTWO
                 };
                 model.Roomimages.Add(gallery);
             }
         }

         // Save the room to the database
         _context.Add(model);
         _context.SaveChanges();
         return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
     }

     return BadRequest(ModelState);
 }
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the check for success and inspected the response? It should be returning, at the least, a status code which will help to determine why it's not successful. Do you have access to the endpoint `"Rooms/addnewRoom"`? What does it expect for the request parameter?

Comment: [400 Status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). If it's returning bad request it could be multiple things, please see link for possible issues. My guess is the api endpoint expects the request body to be of a specific format (not just JSON) but the properties of your model as well need to be checked for accuracy. ie. Trying to pass `string` as `int` or anything like that could cause the request to be rejected.

Comment: You have a link to their API documentation?

Comment: I don't need your code base, I just need to see documentation on the api endpoint you are trying to call. What is the hotel management application? Is it something you are developing or one that already exists?

Comment: Which format the server required? I mean according to your codes, it seems the server need the json format, so you convert the file to base64 and then post to the server? Does the server support the form format?

Comment: You can see an article doing file upload with api at [here](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-consume-api/#upload-files)

Comment: @AlvaMira We are trying to help you, having the documentation for the API endpoint you are trying to call would help alot. With your new error, you can check this post: [web-api-request-throws-error-while-copying-content-to-a-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724514/web-api-request-throws-error-while-copying-content-to-a-stream)

Comment: @AlvaMira you can add new parameter and do model binding. That very easy.

Comment: According the codes you have shared, the server api needs Json format, but your codes steam the byte inside the request body which the asp.net core model binder will not bind well. As I said before, if you still want to use json, you should convert the image to base64, or you should use iformfile instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have made little modifications to your code.

Room:

```
public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile CoverPhoto { get; set; }

    public string? CoverPhotoURL { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Choose the gallery images of the room")]
    [Required]
    [NotMapped]
    public List<IFormFile> GalleryFiles { get; set; }

    public List<RoomImage> Roomimages { get; set; }
}
```

Room Image:

```
public class RoomImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }

    public string? Imageurl { get; set; }

    public Room? Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddNew([FromForm] Room model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            string roomnumber = model.RoomNumber;
            Room imageData = new Room
            {
                RoomNumber = roomnumber,
            };

            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[0];

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(model.CoverPhoto.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                    fileBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)model.CoverPhoto.Length);
                }
            }

            string imgBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
            string imgDataURL = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imgBase64Data);

            model.CoverPhotoURL = imgDataURL;

            //dummy data
            model.Rate = 12;
            model.RoomTypeId = 1;

            if (model.GalleryFiles != null && model.GalleryFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                List<RoomImage> fileDataList = new List<RoomImage>();

                foreach (var file in model.GalleryFiles)
                {
                    if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                    {

                        byte[] galleryFiles = new byte[0];

                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
                            {
                                galleryFiles = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
                            }
                        }

                        string imgBase64Data1 = Convert.ToBase64String(galleryFiles);
                        string imgDataURL1 = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imgBase64Data1);

                        var fileData = new RoomImage
                        {
                            Imageurl = imgDataURL1,
                            RoomId = model.Id,
                        };

                        fileDataList.Add(fileData);
                    }
                }

                imageData.Roomimages = fileDataList;
            }

            string jsonModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imageData);

            StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonModel, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.PostAsync(_httpClient.BaseAddress + "Rooms/addnewRoom", content).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // it is never successful. I don't know why
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return ResponseHelper.SuccessResponse(null, message: "Data Saved Successfully");
        }

        return BadRequest("No valid data was received.");
    }
```

I hope this works!

Comment: Please share your current controller and client codes inside this thread.

Comment: You could edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?** Specifically, _what_ modifications to the code did you make?

Comment: @AlvaMira, the reason why I asked you to update the question is you mentioned your modifying the codes, but facing the new error. Since we don't know which codes you have modified, all the suggest is based on your previous codes which you shared from the github, without seeing your new codes, we couldn't know why it doesn't work. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Actually, it's very easy action, please edit your question with your current server controller's codes(and that action's model class) not the client and I will help modify your codes and post a new answer with client and server based your controller.