# Dealing with Array of Base64 strings in Web Api

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, base64

i'm trying to maintain a project which is trying to post images (yes multiple) from mobile devices to a dot-net web api.

The default content between api and mobile devices is `application/json`.

`public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostExpertiseForm(List<string> images){}`

This is the actual method for posting and in this method they are trying to write base64 strings (`images`) to files.

But the problem is when i tried to call this api, for the first time web api binds `images` with my base64 strings, but all next requests (same request with the first one) are binds to null.

I did some google search and tought about it was a request size problem and i added this lines to `Web.config` :

`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />`

`<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />`

`<jsonSerialization  maxJsonLength="2147483644">`

Didnt work.

What is the real problem here? Why my first request worked?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not about json size. There was a mechanism for logging every response and request, in log request method i saw this line `var request=await Request.ReadAsStringAsync();`

After little searching about parameterless post methods in web api i found that question [why-is-the-body-of-web-api-request-read-once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021089/why-is-the-body-of-a-web-api-request-read-once)

And i realised that i was try to read the request body twice and caused dead lock.

I changed the logic of logging. The problem has gone.