# How to get HttpContent from Request object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpcontent

If a caller adds HttpContent:

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent()) 
{
  HttpContent additionalContent = StringContent("just a test");
  content.Add(additionalContent);
```

Which is then POST'ed, how does the receiver retrieve this additional content?

I've seen examples where people call Request.Content. However, HttpContent.Current.Request doesn't have a Content object.

The receiver is an `[HttpPost]` WebAPI.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494067/read-httpcontent-in-mvc-webapi-controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ReadAsMultipartAsync` extension method for getting content parts and then `ReadAsStringAsync` for parsing string content:

```
var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
var content = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(); //assumed single content part has been sent
if (content != null)
{
    var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Something about changing the method type to Task<HttpResponseMessage>, which I don't want to do.

Comment: What do you mean? How is this related?

Comment: This doesn't work in a method that returns HttpMessageResponse. I don't want to restructure the method just for this.

Comment: If I add .Result, after a long time, an exception is thrown: task was cancelled. "one or more errors occurred". It's vague. I actually catch the error on the client side, even through that line is wrapped in a try/catch on the webapi side.

Comment: And any real reason to not convert web api action to `async Task<HttpResponseMessage>`?

Comment: I don't want to waste time debugging all the side affects. But what difference does it make if that code is throwing some unknown exception?

Comment: First try the `async` version - I'm pretty sure there will be no exception.

Comment: I added async and await from your code above. Once it hits Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync, it skips all the other code and lands on my return (statuscode). So nothing is processed and the client gets a false statuscode.

Comment: Sorry, I had a conditional that was preventing the code from running. It is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think the **body** of your request is nothing but content of request.
Please cross check using *F12 developers tools->Network-> Request's response section or body section*.

Comment: This is in a client app, not web.