# What is the alternate of HttpRequest.EnableRewind() in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: httprequest, buffering, alternate, asp.net-core-3.0

```
BufferingHelper.EnableRewind();
```

Above is an extension method for HttpRequest object in ASP.NET Core 2.2. It is no more there in ASP.NET Core 3.0 (atleast with this name). I want to know it's alternate in ASP.NET Core 3.0. I am not sure if

```
HttpRequestRewindExtensions.EnableBuffering();
```

is the alternate.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12505

Answer (score 134):

The alternate is `HttpRequestRewindExtensions.EnableBuffering()`, indeed. You can see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4ef204e13b88c0734e0e94a1cc4c0ef05f40849e/src/Http/Http/src/Extensions/HttpRequestRewindExtensions.cs#L23) that internally it just calls `EnableRewind()`.

Answer (score 0):

EnableBuffering() internally calls EnableRewind().
We can see below definition of HttpRequestRewindExtensions class.

```
public static class HttpRequestRewindExtensions
{
    public static void EnableBuffering(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        BufferingHelper.EnableRewind(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post duplicate answers; as you can see, this same answer has already been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58089658/16775594). See [answer] for more information on how to write good answers. I also recommend you take the [tour] for a basic intro to what Stack Overflow is.