# Why does StreamReader.ReadToEnd work but not Stream.Read?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to get the body of a request in an ASP.NET Core controller as a `byte[]` array. Here is what I initially wrote:

```
var declaredLength = (int)request.ContentLength;
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[declaredLength];

request.Body.Read(fileBuffer, 0, declaredLength);
```

This code works, but only for small requests (around ~20KB). For larger requests it fills up the first 20,000 or so bytes in the array, then the rest of the array is empty.

I used some code in the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40994711), and was able to read the entire request body successfully after rewriting my code:

```
var declaredLength = (int)request.ContentLength;
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[declaredLength];

// need to enable, otherwise Seek() fails
request.EnableRewind();

// using StreamReader apparently resolves the issue
using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
{
    reader.ReadToEnd();
}

request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
request.Body.Read(fileBuffer, 0, declaredLength);
```

Why is `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` able to read the entire request body successfully, while `Stream.Read()` can't? Reading the request stream twice feels like a hack. Is there a better way to go about this? (I only need to read the stream into a byte array once)

Comment: StreamReader uses a Windows File System method that closes the stream when the EOF is reached while Stream is not being closed by the far end.

Comment: ["An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached"](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read).

Comment: You should definitely look into switching over to [Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that you're trying to read `request.Body` before all of the request has been received yet.

[`Stream.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netframework-4.8) behaves like this:

1. If the end of the stream has been reached, return `0`
2. If there are no bytes available which haven't already been read, block until at least 1 byte is available
3. If 1 or more new bytes are available, return them straight away. Don't block.

As you can see, if the whole body hasn't been received yet, `request.Body.Read(...)` will just return the part of the body that has been received.

`StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` calls `Stream.Read` [in a loop](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,436), until it finds the end of the stream.

You should probably call `Stream.Read` in a loop as well, until you've read all of the bytes:

```
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[declaredLength];
int numBytesRead = 0;
while (numBytesRead < declaredLength)
{
    int readBytes = request.Body.Read(fileBuffer, numBytesRead, declaredLength - numBytesRead);
    if (readBytes == 0)
    {
        // We reached the end of the stream before we were expecting it
        // Might want to throw an exception here?
    }
    numBytesRead += readBytes;
}
```