# Reading from request body in an authorization requirement handler breaks routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, stream, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a custom handler for security and an endpoint. It works as supposed to.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
    AwoRequirement requirement)
{
    HttpRequest request = Accessor.HttpContext.Request;
    string awo = request.Headers
        .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Key == "awo").Value.ToString();
    ...
    bools authorized = ...;

    if (authorized) context.Succeed(requirement);
    else context.Fail();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

[Authorize(Policy = "SomePolicy"), HttpPost("something")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Something([FromBody] Thing dto)
{ ... }
```

Now, I need to check the contents of the body, so I'm reading it in and analyze the contents. However, I noticed that with this addition, the endpoint isn't reached anymore. No exception or anything, just simply no hit, like if the route doesn't match. While debugging, I saw that the stream is used up so breakpointing the flow and reading again produces an empty string.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync( ... )
{
    HttpRequest request = Accessor.HttpContext.Request;
    ...
    using StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Accessor.HttpContext.Request.Body);
    string body = stream.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
    Thing thing = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Thing>(body);
    if (thing.IsBad())
      authorized &= fail;
    ...
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50351485/1525840) I should rewind seeking zero point of the stream, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51853606/1525840) suggests enabling of buffering too. (There's also suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40994711/1525840) but there's no `await` in the sample, which is required on my system, so I couldn't try it out properly.) Based on that, I landed in the following.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync( ... )
{
    HttpRequest request = Accessor.HttpContext.Request;
    ...
    Accessor.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
    using StreamReader stream 
      = new StreamReader(Accessor.HttpContext.Request.Body);
    string body = stream.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
    Thing thing = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Thing>(body);
    if (thing.IsBad())
      authorized &= fail;
    ...
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Now, going back and rerunning the code does read in from the stream again. However, the endpoint isn't found anymore still, just like before adding the above. It is reached if I remove the reading from the stream, though, so I sense that I'm still affecting the body reading somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried leaving the body stream open and rewind it, by using the [StreamReader overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) that leaves the baseStream open and after using it to set `Accessor.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0`?

Comment: Can you rewind the stream?   I would be very surprised if this was possible, especially for large streams.   It's not like the server would cache it anywhere, and HTTP doesn't allow for replaying message bodies.

Comment: According to the linked answers, it should be possible by using `Accessor.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering()`

Comment: @Neil It seems that I can, although only inside the handler. My stream read a body of, maybe, 300 bytes (not even 1 kb), so the size shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You seem to be trying to access some sort of authorisation data in the body of 'every' message?   This sounds very non-standard (for the reasons you are now coming across).  Is this method the 'best' solution, or should you be looking at authentication in a different way?   Headers (X-AUTH-XXX, or Authorization, etc etc) are 'easier'.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the suggestions. This specific question considers the strange effect my reading from the stream has on the routing. It should work but for some strange reason , it doesn't. Let's hope someone who's got specific experience with this issue comes along. As for the suggestion itself, the concern is that the payload needs to be investigated and I don't control how it arrives. My work-around is to explicitly check it in the method receiving it. It works but I want to do it properly in the handler. Also, regardless, it's good to know why something supposed to work, doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you need to check **if the user is allowed to perform an action on the submitted resource** (`Thing`) according to a policy.

[The way to go about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is to implement an `IAuthorizationHandler`, which lets you pass & inspect the resource in question.

Assume we have a `Post` class:

```cs
interface IAuthored
{
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
}

class Post : IAuthored
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

We want to allow only the post author to make edits on it.

Here's the controller. I've added an `[Authorize]` to let only the authenticated users in.

```cs
public class PostController : ControllerBase
{
    private AppDbContext _dbContext;
    private IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

    public PostController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService, AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [Authorize] // this wouldn't work! [*]
    [HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditPost(string id)
    {
        var post = await _dbContext.Set<Post>().FindAsync(id);

        // oops! any authenticated user can edit this post.

        post.Title = "asd";
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Normally, with a simple policy, we'd annotate the action with `[Authorize("my_policy")]`. But it wouldn't work here, because `[Authorize]` attributes are evaluated (in authorization middleware) before the execution reaches the controller. ASP.NET Core (or you) cannot know which resource is being handled [*].

So we need to imperatively authorize the action. We define a requirement, and a policy that enforces it.

```cs
// just a marker class
class AuthorRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

services.AddAuthorization(
    options => {
        options.AddPolicy("editor", builder => builder.Requirements.Add(new AuthorRequirement()));
    }
);
```

Then implement a handler for this requirement. We can subclass `AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement, TResource>` or `AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement>`. I'm opting to authorize all classes that implement `IAuthored` interface.

```cs
class AuthorRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AuthorRequirement, IAuthored> // for a specific
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AuthorRequirement requirement, IAuthored resource)
    {
        var userId = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (resource.AuthorId == userId)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        // ... let other handlers take a stab at this
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This works, but we're forced to handle authorization imperatively inside the action.

[*]: If we can infer the resource before it hits the endpoint, we can short-circuit the whole operation.

Let's create an extension method that lets us read the request body multiple times, and enable request buffering.

```cs
internal static class HttpRequestExtensions {
    public static async Task<T> ReadAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpRequest request, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        request.Body.Position = 0;
        var result = await request.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>(options);
        // reset the position again to let endpoint middleware read it
        request.Body.Position = 0;
        return result;
    }
}


app.Use((context, next) => {
    context.Request.EnableBuffering(1_000_000);
    return next();
});

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Now we can rewrite the handler to read the body and perform authorization "declaratively" [^1].

```cs
class AuthorRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AuthorRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AuthorRequirementHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AuthorRequirement requirement)
    {
        var endpoint = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetEndpoint();
        var action  = endpoint.Metadata.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().FirstOrDefault();
        // is the action is expecting a post DTO
        if (!action.Parameters.Any(p => p.ParameterType == typeof(Post)))
        {
            return;
        }
        
        var post = await _httpContextAccessor!.HttpContext!.Request.ReadAsJsonAsync<Post>();
        var userId = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (post.AuthorId == userId)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}
```

Once the user is authorized, the request follows the middleware chain and reaches the `EndpointMiddleware`, which reads & parses the request again, and delegates it to the controller action.

---

[^1]: I'd actually **advise against** this approach as it mixes authorization, which is a business requirement, with implementation details (HTTP) that it shouldn't know anything about. It's also not testable, unlike the previous approach.

Comment: Once thing that confuses me is the implementation of `ReadAsJsonAsync<T>(...)`. Perhaps I'm missing something in the flow but to me it looks like invoking it on an instance of `HttpContext` will call the method itself and, once there, it will recursively invoke itself again and again without an end. If it was an intentional recursive call, I fail to see the base case where it returns an actual value. What do I miss?

Comment: No no, I'm calling a different method, check again. It's confusing but I'm open for better naming suggestions :)

Comment: Ahem... I know that it's not how the site is supposed to be used. With that disclaimer (and with assurance of inconvenient shamefulness), I wonder if you'd like to take a look at [this issue I have with logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326555/cant-remove-cookies-using-c-sharp/69344625?noredirect=1#comment122565314_69344625). I've worked out everything else (largely thanks to your contribution) but the last part is a no go. After days of research, I realize that I'm stuck. If you don't have time, I totally and utterly understand. I'm still immensely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the code [here](https://github.com/alicommit-malp/Dotnet-Core-Request-Body-Peeker/blob/d18dc111c88dcf339b003ac93eea46652ea6d7ff/src/Request.Body.Peeker/HttpRequestExtension.cs). Either use the nuget package or just copy the method you need and if you wish to follow latest trends, rewrite it using `Memory<byte>`