# How to log the request url when an error occurs in asp net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-logging

Why does this code only gets executed when no error has occurred?

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    Console.WriteLine(context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested);

    if(context.Response.StatusCode < 200 || context.Response.StatusCode > 299) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Method);
        Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Path);
    }
    
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Is there an easy way to log the url and optionally body of the request when an unhandled exception occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494913/how-to-read-request-body-in-an-asp-net-core-webapi-controller) to get to know how to extract the request body, and then for when exception happen, use something like

```
// remember to put this as high in the pipeline as you need
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
                try
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // Extract Http request body, logging out the exception,... everything that you see necessary
                }
            });
```