# Access [FromBody] from a Custom Attribute Authorization

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-authorization

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorization(permissions: new string[] { "default" })]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] UserModel userModel)
    {
       
    }
```

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
    {
        
        private readonly string[] _permissions;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public AuthorizationAttribute(params string[] permissions)
        {            
            _permissions = permissions;
        }

        public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (_permissions == null || _permissions.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            //How do I access userModel here
            
        }
        
    }
```

Basically I would like to access [frombody]userModel in my authorization class so that we can authorize.

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't feel right. Why would authorization be contingent on the request content like this?

Comment: We have an Id which is passed through FromBody model class and we would like to authorize based on it.

Comment: I believe model binding happens after auhorization so you there won't be anything meaningful assigned to the model anyway. You will have to inspect the request body directly.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494913/how-to-read-request-body-in-an-asp-net-core-webapi-controller