# Cannot access disposed object CopyToASync(ms)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just hit post call and i have request and response both. I have method in which i am trying to log request and repose body in my db for that i am just building req and response body.

```
internal static async Task<string> GetBodyForLoggingAsync(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return await GetBodyForLoggingAsync(request.Content);
}

private static async Task<string> GetBodyForLoggingAsync(HttpContent content)
{
    if (content == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    string requestBody = null;

    var contentType = content.Headers.ContentType;

    if (contentType == null || _contentTypesWhereBodyIsLogged.Contains(contentType.MediaType))
    {
        try
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(" ---- GETTING BODY CONTENT");

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    await content.CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        requestBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var test = ex;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var test = ex;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error of cannot access disposed object in content.CopyToAsync() method for POST and PATCH call and if i do same call from postman making it get i am not getting this error. I know there is no use of body in get call but just i was checking.

Comment: It's hard to tell the context that you're dealing with the HttpContent in can you post the stack trace? If I had to guess, your logging is occurring after the framework has disposed of the request and response. If that's the case you want to move your middleware further up the pipeline.

Comment: Response it getting logged it happens incase of request only.

Comment: Probably duplicate of these questions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494913/how-to-read-request-body-in-a-asp-net-core-webapi-controller
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494067/read-httpcontent-in-webapi-controller

Comment: No my code throws error when i try to do Copy or Read anything with the error of disposed object.

Comment: Any update on this?