# I am trying to retrieve input request from HttpRequest message. Content in HttpRequest showing content type and length. How do I get json out?

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-web-api

Current code

```
if (!(context.Exception is exception))
    HttpContent requestContent = context.Request.Content;
    string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

`Jsoncontent` returns null here as well as

```
context.request = context.HttpRequestMessage
```

Seeing below output in local window

```
context.Request.Content.Headers {
    Content-Length: 1458
    Content-Type: application/json
    }
Allow: {}
ContentDisposition: null
ContentEncoding: {}
ContentLanguage: {}
ContentLength: 1458
ContentLocation: null
ContentMD5: null
ContentRange: null
ContentType: { application/json }
Expires: null
LastModified: null
Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
context.Request.Content { System.Net.Http.StreamContent }
Headers: {
    Content-Length: 1458
    Content-Type: application/json
}
```

How do I retrieve content from header?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: C#.public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)  
        {
     if (!(context.Exception is ClientErrorException))
            {
   
   HttpContent requestContent = context.Request.Content;
                string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    }

Comment: public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)  
        {
     if (!(context.Exception is ClientErrorException))
            {
   
   HttpContent requestContent = context.Request.Content;
                string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want content-type and length as json string, you can use

```
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Content.Headers);

 // Sample output 
 // "[{\"Key\":\"Content-Length\",\"Value\":[\"29\"]},{\"Key\":\"Content-Type\",\"Value\":[\"application/json\"]}]"
```

requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync() return empty string because body can only be read once. If you want to read body using ReadAsStringAsync then remove parameter from actions (this will prevent default model binding).

```
   // This will have Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync as ""
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult>  Post(MyModel model)
```

Change it to

```
   // This will have Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync as json string
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult>  Post()
```

Blog explains this in more detail https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding/

Hope this help

**Update**

If you need request details in exception filter then you can use following options

**Options 1** (easier and I would advise to use this)

Use

```
       context.ActionContext.ActionArguments
```

Example

```
        var requestJson = $"RequestUrl: {context.Request.RequestUri} " +
                          $"ActionName: {context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName} " +
                          $"Arguments: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.ActionContext.ActionArguments)}";

        Debug.WriteLine(requestJson);
```

**Options 2** copy RequestStream to MemoryStream and reread from position 0 (copied from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362781/how-to-get-raw-request-body-in-asp-net))

```
        string request;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var requestStream = await context.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            requestStream.Position = 0;
            requestStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                request = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(request)
```

Comment: Thank you kaushal. i need to have my model in post, is there any way to overcome this like by using seek or something else?

Comment: As far as I know, no you cannot read body stream twice in web api. Why you need to read content twice? If you already have model bounded, I am not sure why would you need to read it twice? If you need only content-type and content length, then you can get it from Request.Content.Headers (and its available without any restriction)

Comment: i want to read request body in global.asax global on exception method for logging purpose. Model is not available in global.asax.                                    is there any other way to over come this situation?

Comment: I haven't tried it in global.asax however seems its possible. Please try solution from  https://stackoverflow.com/q/6362781/7500843 using seek. If it doesn't work, I will try code and will update later

Comment: i have tried with streamreader. i am getting below error                  This "method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked"

Comment: tried this                                                                                 HttpRequest request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);

                try
                {
                    string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                }

Comment: tried below one also                                                                                        string data;
    using (var stream = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
    {
        if (stream.CanSeek)
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
        }
        data = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    return data;     stream.canseek coming as false and tream.position is only readable.

Comment: Please check update section of answer. Hope this help.